# Refactoring C# Code

Tags: c#, templates

I'm new to C# but I'm coming from a c++ background.

Could these three functions be refactored to just a single function with templates?
Kindly note that those three functions are NOT in a Generic class.

```
private void CheckValue(bool temp, ref bool variable)
    {
        if (temp != variable)
        {
            variable = temp;
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
        }
    }

    private void CheckValue(float temp, ref float variable)
    {
        if (temp != variable)
        {
            variable = temp;
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
        }
    }

    private void CheckValue(int temp, ref int variable)
    {
        if (temp != variable)
        {
            variable = temp;
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would it be *invalid* for someone to provide two similar types that aren't one of these three types?

Comment: @Servy its just a Unity object.

Comment: Also note C# doesn't have templates.  It has generics, which are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question it seems that all the code is doing is validating the variable and compare it to some temporary value and if it is different assign the temp to the variable.

I have a helper class in my commonlib that have a function that will validate the proper type of the passed value and return either the value of the desired type or a default for the desired type back to the caller.

So you could add this to the project with reference and use call like:

```
var variable = Helper.Validate<put your type here>(temp);
```

OR

```
var tmp = Helper.Validate<put your type here>(temp);
var variable = !variable.Equal(tmp) ? tmp : variable 
EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);


using System.ComponentModel;
namespace CommonLib.Helpers
{
 public static  partial class Helper
 {
     public static T Validate<T>(object param)
    {
        return TryParse<T>(param);
    }

       private static T TryParse<T>(object inValue)
        {
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

            try
            {
               return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(inValue.ToString().Trim());
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using generic types?

```
private void CheckValue<T>(T temp, ref T variable)
{
    if (temp != variable)
    {
        variable = temp;
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: The method can now be called with more than just these 3 types.  That may not be valid.

Comment: @AmmarCSE the class is not a generic class, its just a normal class, that has those three functions.

Comment: Also, you can't use the `!=` operator with generic types. Probably have to replace it with `if(!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(temp, variable))`

Comment: @Andre That's not a problem.  The class need not be generic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this, at least directly.You **can't** specify the type should be `bool`, `float` or `int`.The nearest thing you can do is using a `struct` constraint then perform a `type-check`, if the type is not one of the supported types throw an exception.

Here is an example:

```
private static void CheckValue<T>(T temp,  T variable) where T : struct 
{
   if (!new[] {typeof (bool), typeof (float), typeof (int)}.Contains(typeof (T)))
   {
          // invalid type
   }
   if (temp.Equals(variable))
   {
      EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);     
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course you've now lost all compile time type safety, so you're really better off using the OP's code over this.

Comment: @Servy yes, the life would be easier if we could specify a constraint like `where T : int,float,bool` :/

Answer (score 0):

C# having awesome Generic type. You can use this to do things in a single method.

```
private void CheckValue<T>(T temp, ref T variable)
{
    if (temp != variable)
    {
        variable = temp;
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use generic types, however you'll need the "where T : class" at the end to get the comparison to compile because type T is not necessarily a reference type...

```
    private static void CheckValue<T>(T temp, ref T variable) where T : class
    {
        if (temp != variable)
        {
            variable = temp;
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now none of the three type's he's using can be used for this method, due to the class restriction.